# My sql: PacketTooBigException: Packet for query is too large (4,739,923 > 65,535)

Tags: mysql, jdbc, max-allowed-packet

I am trying to connect to a database on my `raspbery pi`. I have `mysql` downloaded on the pi and have created a database on there already. I am trying to use driver manager to connect.

Here is my code for it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String host = "jdbc:mysql://scheduleit.duckdns.org:99/scheduleit";
        String uName = username;
        String uPass = password;
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have gone into the configuration files and changed the `max_allowed_packet` to `32M` for [`mysqldump`]. I looked through the other configuration files and was unable to find another max_allowed_packet field to edit. Additionally, I have used the command: `SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=32M;` in `mysql`.

One thing I was curious about was whether the hostname was wrong. I ssh into the pi using port 99, but perhaps I use a different port when connecting with a `DriverManager`? The default port for `mysql` is 3306 and I tried that, but wasn't getting a connection.

Finally, I am using `mariadb`, which to my understanding is essentially mysql, since I log into using the `mysql -u root -p` command. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps `jdbc:mysql://scheduleit.duckdns.org:99/scheduleit?max_allowed_packet=<value>`... There are two different parameters called `max_allowed_packet`, one on the server and one on the client.  The error suggests the problem is on the client, not the server.

Answer (score 5):

Both the MySQL Server and the client (JDBC in this case) must increase their setting for max_allowed_packet. The max is effectively the *lesser* of the configuration of the client and the server.

For the server, you change this with `SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet`. You should also change it in the server's `my.cnf` file because `SET GLOBAL` changes are lost when the server restarts.

For the client, as Michael commented above, you can specify this as a property in the JDBC URL. Except JDBC properties are spelled in **camelCase**.

```
String host = "jdbc:mysql://scheduleit.duckdns.org:99/scheduleit?maxAllowedPacket=33554432";
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html for more documentation on JDBC URL properties.

Comment: Thank you very much! The trick that fixed the issue for me was to set the property both in server and the client.